# Using ExcelWriter in pandas how to generate multiple sheets output

Tags: python, pandas

In my data set, I want to generate total 180 sheets.

```
Final=[]
for i in q2:
    :
    :
    Df=pd.concat([SHT_elements,SMT_elements,SLT_elements],axis=0)
    Final.append(Df)  

from pandas import ExcelWriter
writer = ExcelWriter('datafortrail.xlsx')

Final[0].to_excel(writer, 'sheet1')
Final[1].to_excel(writer, 'sheet2')
Final[2].to_excel(writer, 'sheet3')
:
:
Final[179].to_excel(writer, 'sheet180')
writer.save()
```

Is there any way for the code to automatically identify the number of sheets to be generate, so I don't need to type `Final[].to_excel(writer,'')` 180 times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `for idx in range(len(df_list))`means : I want the length of my array. Then, using `range()`, I will make a list from 0 to the length of my array. And then, with the for loop, we will iterate through the newly created list. Here, in my case, since my list contains 10 dataframes, it'll go from 0 to 9.

I'll access the ten elements of the list using 0 to 9 indexes, and then, using the string `format()` method, I'll make a new name for each sheet.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a' : range(5)
})

df_list = [df.copy() for _ in range(10)] #  Making a list of 10 dataframes.

writer = ExcelWriter('some_excel.xlsx')
for idx in range(len(df_list)):
    df_list[idx].to_excel(writer, "sheet{}".format(idx+1))

writer.save()
```